# why value of f not changing to 1 when even number is provided?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
p=[]
l=[]
v="run"
a=int(input("enter num or end: "))
while v!="end":
    l.append(int(a))
    a=input("enter num or end: ")
    v=a  
for a in l:
    f=0
    for j in range(2,a//2):
         if a%j == 0:
            f=1
            break
    if f==0:
        p.append(a)
```

here I am inputting numbers and if its a prime number then I am putting it to list 'p' and at last output p.
i cant understand why 1st if statement not working when I am providing an even number like in picture below 4 is inputed so it should have changed value of f to 1 so that it doesn't get into list 'p' but its not. i am very new to python so there is possibility of silly mistakes.

[image]
on left code, on right output

Comment: Where in this code should `f` be increasing? It appears the only `f` assignments are `f=0` and `f=1`?

Comment: because you are not incrementing f. why should it increase by itself.

Comment: damn i am so bad at asking question, I should have provided some context first. i have edited the question see if you can understand or I will edit it again

Comment: You `break` immediately after setting `f=1`. Which takes you back to the top of the outer for loop then you immediately set back to `f=0`.

Comment: i am writing a code to check if a number is prime and if it is prime then copying it to another list 'p', for that I am using a flag f if f is 0 then append if not then skip

Comment: When `a` is 4, `range(2,a//2)` is an empty sequence (going from 2 to less than 2), so you aren't actually testing any possible factors.  Adding 1 to the upper bound would be the simple fix, although mathematically speaking it's the square root of the number that is the true upper bound by which you're going to find a factor if one exists.

Comment: i checked it again after removing break now its working for all other number but not for 4

Comment: okayyy, i got it thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `range(2, 4//2)` is an empty range, since 4//2 = 2, and `range(2, 2)` includes every integer less than 2, starting with 2 - which is to say, no integers.

You will not have this issue with test numbers greater than 4, since in those cases you will always have at least 2 in the range of potential factors that you're testing.

Answer (score 0):

It is because for 4 your statement:
for j in range(2, n//2):
becomes for j in range(2,2). if you have the same start and end in a range it does nothing. So it does not do the a % j and does not change f. In any case, if you are trying to check whether it is a prime number the range should be (2, int(n**0.5))